# unicode data with custom font doesn't work properly in ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, fonts

I am using custom font for label and string which I am getting from unicode characters.
And the font is not changing.
here is the snippet of my code:

```
 NSString* str = @"\u05D0\u05D1\u05D2";
[mMatchingLabel setText:str];
mMatchingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"David New Hebrew" size:26];
```

But when I write for example :

```
NSString* str = @"label";  [mMatchingLabel setText:str];
mMatchingLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"David New Hebrew" size:26];
```

The font effect is evident.

Can someone explain what's here wrong?

Comment: That font is not a unicode font?

Comment: What I mean is it does not have the unicode glyphs in it that you are requesting. Try it out on a Mac and see there. Fonts may or may not have a glyph for any given unicode point.